# URL path not working in when deployed in WebLogic server

Tags: java, rest, weblogic, java-web-start

type here

I am trying to build REST API, I have created the web application project using maven and included jersey dependencies in pom.xml file. Also I have included web.xml file and weblogic.xml file in web-inf folder. when deployed and execute the URL path index.jsp is working fine. but other URL is not working it show the Not found. Unable to find what is wrong.

**Web.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Rest service</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.vno.testaddress</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.9/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>14.1.1.0</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>/address</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>

            <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>io.swagger.core.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>io.swagger.parser.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

**Java code:**

```
    import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class Testaddress 
{
     @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String getIt() {
            return "Hello world!";
        }
}
```

**Error:**

I am trying to use this url :**http://192.168.77.10:7001/testaddress-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/webapi/myresource**  and expecting the result as "Hello World!" but it shows not found.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 potential issues:

1. Your class TestAddress has no package defined. If it's defined (but not displayed here), I think it should be "com.vno.testaddress" to comply with the init-param> defined for your ServletContainer in web.xml
2. The value defined for your "wls:context-root" parameter is "/address". So, to access your class and make it work, I think your URL should be "http://192.168.77.10:7001/address/webapi/myresource "

Let me know

Comment: For point number one, package is defined and included in ServletContainer in web.xml. For point 2, http://192.168.77.10:7001/address/webapi/myresource  gives error as 404

Comment: is there any mistake in web.xml file

Comment: when I see the weblogic server, it shows http://desktop-2r433ks:7001/address/webapi/application.wadl as test point is that makes the issue

Comment: I found jersey 3.1.0 has jakarta.ws.rs, Jakarta not support in Weblogic server 14C, when use jersey 1.8 it works fine